# C# Format list items with BAR between words

Tags: c#, list, loops

My code is currently busted and I am aware of this. I'm working one one part at a time and I have hit two stumbling blocks which I'm hoping to find help here in regards too.

I am trying to address my formatting issue with this question here.

With the code below, i read in a text file using StreamReader, and the selections come in all on the same line as I want them too seperated by a BAR ("|"). Unfortunately, the bar prints at the end of each word, not actually 'between' each word. I don't want the last bar to print. I know i could cheat and add a bar to the font with a Console.Write("|") but that would be cheating in my mind - i wouldn't really be printing/displaying a bar between the words as I was trying to make a more elegant console selection.

This is just something I'm doing to learn and is not part of our assignment, but i like to push myself when I can. I am very very new to attempting to code, I am a complete newb, please assume I know nothing and please know all help is very much appreciated.

THIS IS MY CODE THUS FAR:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

using System.Threading.Tasks;// Needed for Streaming...
using System.IO;// Needed for Streaming...

namespace a090___StreamReader_DictionarySearch
{
class Program
{
    private const String FILE_NAME = "dictionary.txt";//establish text file instance

    public void Play()
    {
        do
        {
            DisplayTitle();

            List<Listing> items = LoadListings();//create a list of WordDef objects

            int count = 0;
            foreach (Listing myListing in items)//read in items from file
            {
                //Console.WriteLine(myListing.GetName() + ": " + myListing.GetDefinition());
                Console.Write(myListing.GetName());

                if (count != items.Count - 1)
                {
                    Console.Write(" | ");
                }


                count++;
            }

            DisplayText("\n\nPlease enter a word from the selections about to see it's definition");// Nice use of PROMPT
            String userSelection = Console.ReadLine().ToLower();//Capture input

            /// What are we trying to do?
            /// Collect value entered for comparison - chek!
            /// 
            /// Compare value entered against list (Does value match to name?)
            /// IF value matches print description
            /// if value does not match(Else), state no match

            //if (userSelection == Listing.name)
            //{Console.WriteLine("You selected: " + userSelection() + 
            //                   "\nWhich Means: " + Listing.GetDefinition());}
            //else{Console.WriteLine("I'm sorry, I don't have a match for that.");}

        } while (PlayAgain());

        Salutation();
    }

    //ToolBox -- my program specific tools
    public List<Listing> LoadListings()//load entries display as list
    {
        StreamReader fileIn = new StreamReader(FILE_NAME);
        List<Listing> entry = new List<Listing>();

        //loop through every line of the file
        while (!fileIn.EndOfStream)
        {
            String line = fileIn.ReadLine();
            String[] pieces = line.Split(':');

            if (pieces.Length < 1) continue;//error handling - set to length of text items

            Listing myListing = new Listing(pieces[0], pieces[1]);
            entry.Add(myListing);
        }
        fileIn.Close(); return entry;
    }




    //MaxBox -- my useful tools
    public void DisplayText(String StringNameIs)
    { Console.WriteLine(StringNameIs); }//Where are we? 

    public Boolean PlayAgain()
    {
        Console.Write("\n\nDo you select again? (y)es or (n)o: ");
        String command = Console.ReadLine().ToLower();

        if (command == "y" || command == "yes") return true;
        return false;
    }

    public void Salutation()
    { Console.Clear(); Console.WriteLine("Ti Do - oh - oh Ti Do -- So Do!"); } //The last line from the 'do-re-mi' song from the Sound of Music

    public void DisplayTitle()
    { Console.Clear(); Console.WriteLine(">>>-- A Dictionary of Sounds --<<< \n"); } //Announce Our Program  



    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Program DictionaryLookup = new Program();
        DictionaryLookup.Play();
        Console.Read();
    }
}
}
```

Please note: I have searched StackOverflow, GOOGLE, BING, MS' resources, et al. for an answer i can understand with my limited skills/understanding. I've also been working on this for a few hours.  Please help.

Comment: If it is taking the text file in as one long string, you could use the `.Split()` method with a '.' as your delimiter, couldn't you?

Comment: I am not familiary with the .Split() (Title case?). I did an incremented sort of method up above that works. but i don't know that it's the most elegant solution. How would i do a .Split()

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're looking for [`string.Join`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.String.Join%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Replace the whole `foreach` loop

```
foreach (Listing myListing in items)//read in items from file
{
    //Console.WriteLine(myListing.GetName() + ": " + myListing.GetDefinition());
    Console.Write(myListing.GetName() + " | ");
}
```

with

```
Console.Write(string.Join(" | ", items.Select(x => x.GetName())));
```

Comment: WOW That is some impressive elegance there Tim S. You did what i was trying with a line. I applaud you. My solution that i worked up was like 8 lines. Always a better way, thanks for helping. I'm still tryign to understand what you are doing but man it works. I will be digging into this solution for the next hour. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively,  you could try a writing a backspace to the console.

Edit: As noted in the comments, you'd need to print a space char over the last pipe.

```
Console.Write("\b \b");
```

Comment: Writing just a backspace to the console window will not remove the pipe character after the last word.  You need to use `Console.Write("\b \b");` to backspace the cursor, overwrite the pipe character, and then backspace the cursor again.

Answer (score 1):

```
List<Listing> items = LoadListings(); //create a list of WordDef objects
int checklast = 0;
foreach (Listing myListing in items) //read in items from file
{
    if (checklast == items.Count-1)
    {
        Console.Write(myListing.GetName());
    }
    else
    {
        //Console.WriteLine(myListing.GetName() + ": " +  myListing.GetDefinition());
        Console.Write(myListing.GetName() + " | ");
    }
    ++checklast;
}
```

You can use the lazy method by checking when the last item will come so you make sure won't add BAR at the end.

Answer (score 1):

You may convert List of objects to array of object property and cast it to a string with delimeter:

```
string str = String.Join(" | ", items.Select(x => x.GetName()).ToArray());
```

Answer (score 1):

try something like this...

```
        var items = LoadListings();//create a list of WordDef objects
        int i = 1;
        var sw = new StringBuilder();

        foreach(var myListing in items)
        {

            sw.AppendFormat("{0}", myListing.GetName() + "|");

            if (i=items.Count)
            {
                sw.Replace("|", "", i,i);
            }else 
            { i++; }
        }

        //Console.WriteLine(myListing.GetName() + ": " + myListing.GetDefinition());
        Console.Write(sw);
```